# Subsonic 3.1 when is it likely?

Tags: subsonic, medium-trust

I have a project built around Subsonic 3.0.0.3 and have run into the dreaded medium trust issue, can anyone tell me is there a way I can mod the code myself to get this working or what the expected timescale for 3.1 version is?  Its looking increasingly like I will have to ditch subsonic to get my system running

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 1):

No timeframe for SubSonic 3.1 (or 3.0.0.4), but here are the current plans: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/browse_thread/thread/caae09418ce4d975/

The SubSonic Google discussion group is the best place to find out about the current development happenings for SubSonic.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, as soon as possible. 
Long answer, there's a number of things planned for 3.1 these include (but are not necessarily limited to):

1. Oracle support
2. MediumTrust support
3. Automatic mapping of collections in SimpleRepository

These are all in development right now but before they become the main focus we need to get version 3.0.0.4 out the door with fixes for a lot of the outstanding issues listed on github. There's also a lot of more boring work going on behind the scenes which should make regular and stable releases easier.
The current release schedule is:

- Version 3.0.0.4 - 22nd March 2010
- Version 3.1 - 22nd May 2010